AnswerRelevancyMetric not showing results on LLM evaluation
i've got this code :
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
from deepeval.models.base_model import DeepEvalBaseLLM

class AzureOpenAI(DeepEvalBaseLLM):
    def __init__(
        self,
        model
    ):
        self.model = model

    def load_model(self):
        return self.model

    def generate(self, prompt: str) -> str:
        chat_model = self.load_model()
        return chat_model.invoke(prompt).content

    async def a_generate(self, prompt: str) -> str:
        chat_model = self.load_model()
        res = await chat_model.ainvoke(prompt)
        return res.content

    def get_model_name(self):
        return "Custom Azure OpenAI Model"

# Replace these with real values
custom_model = AzureChatOpenAI(
    deployment_name=azure_openai_model, 
    api_key=azure_openai_secret.value, 
    azure_endpoint=azure_openai_endpoint, 
    api_version=azure_openai_api_version, 
    verbose=False, 
    streaming=True,
    temperature=0,
    callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]
)
azure_openai = AzureOpenAI(model=custom_model)

As I want to evaluate it, I used this piece of code :
from deepeval.metrics import AnswerRelevancyMetric
from deepeval.test_case import LLMTestCase

# Initialize a test case
     test_case = LLMTestCase(
     input="The dog chased the cat up the tree, who ran up the tree?",
     actual_output="It depends, some might consider the cat, while others might argue the dog.",
expected_output="The cat."know."],
)

# Initialize metric
metric_ = AnswerRelevancyMetric(model=azure_openai)

I also do a pip install :
%pip install nest-asyncio

I'm referring to this link : source code for the test
As to print the results from this evaluation, I use :
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


print(metric_.score)
#None    
print(metric_.measure(test_case))

And I get this error message :
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.

